# how to change html of dialog dynamically in onsen

Tags: android, jquery, dialog, onsen-ui

I'm trying to dynamically change the html content of a dialog of `onse.ui`, but it is not working for me, my code is as below:

Here my html code.

```
<ons-template id="popupFechaCalendario.html">
    <ons-dialog  style="height: 300px;" var="naviDialog" cancelable>
        <ons-navigator var="myNav">
            <ons-toolbar inline>
               <div class="center contenedorPopup" id="popupFechaCalendario_fecha">html content</div>
            </ons-toolbar>
        </ons-navigator>
     </ons-dialog>
</ons-template>
```

And here my Javascript code.

```
$("#popupFechaCalendario_fecha").html("some html...");

ons.createDialog('popupFechaCalendario.html').then(function(dialog) {
    dialog.show();
});
```

I have also tried like,

```
ons.createDialog('popupFechaCalendario.html').then(function(dialog) {
    dialog.on("preshow", function(e) {
        $("#popupFechaCalendario_fecha").html("some html...");
    });
    dialog.show();
});
```

In advance thank you very much to anyone who can help me

Comment: What is the error you get ?  Because, all seems to be ok

Comment: It's working here: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/YywRQR

Comment: Have you inserted the `ons.createDialog` function inside a `ons.ready` function? Otherwise, it will try to create the dialog before the DOM is fully initialized, which means that `<ons-template id="popupFechaCalendario.html">` has not been created yet.

Comment: Yes, it seems the problem was because I was using Dialog.Show (), should use naviDialog.show (), as it was called by the externally as in your example, thank you very much for your help